# Typescript Visual Studio 2015 claims version 1.4 instead of 1.7.6

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Typescript 1.7.6 for Visual Studio 2015, I'm getting VS telling me that I'm using 1.4 .... why? How do I get VS to recognise the 1.7.6 compiler....

[image]

Comment: Check the `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` in the project file. Normally VS offers to update this for you, but maybe in this case VS did not.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers haha the project states 1.6 ...... `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

Comment: @ChrisChilvers and annoyingly, this didnt fix it... I don't understand why this is difficult for the Typescript and VS team....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have resharper installed?

I have resharper 9.2 installed and that doesn't understand TypeScript 1.7.6 so it's autodetect feature doesn't work.

Open up Resharper Options -> TypeScript -> Inspections and change Auto-detection to the latest version of TypeScript that shows up.

Comment: yeah not a bad shout that!